# How to get data from XML in placeholder?

Tags: xml, html, placeholder

I am creating HTML template in which I will get the data from XML file. I am using placeholder. Eg. < input type="text" placeholder=""/> However, I am want to display data in the placeholder from XML, how can I do this in HTML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)